# How to access array values from a cross-reference array with angular (click)

Tags: arrays, angular, loops, correspondence

I have a cross-reference array:

```
examples = [{name: "ex1",steps: 'ex1Steps'},
          {name: "ex2",steps:'ex2Steps'},
          {name: "ex3",steps:'ex3Steps'}];
```

and 3 arrays

```
ex1Steps
...
ex3Steps=[{name...},{...}]
```

I would like to access to these last arrays values with a ngfor loop from examples array.
I tried some things like:

```
        <mat-list>
      <div>Examples :</div>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let example of examples;let i=index;" (click)="selectedExample = {examples[i].steps}">
          <mat-list-item>{{example.name}}</mat-list-item>
        </ng-container>
    </mat-list>
```

and:

```
                <mat-vertical-stepper>
                    <mat-step *ngFor="let step of example.steps" [label]="step.name">
```

Comment: Why don't you use the array directly in the object [{name: "ex1",steps: [{name...},{...}]}] ?

Comment: because the 3 arrays are already very big with multiple levels and I don't want to add another level...